# Is it possible to list Oracle tnsnames.ora data with an SQL query from inside Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm connecting to a remote Oracle database via SQL Developer. I would like to if possible pull out the information from tnsnames.ora (stored on the remote computer). Is this information from tnsnames.ora present anywhere in the database that I could read with a query?

Or, if it's possible to rebuild the information present in tnsnames.ora by querying a number of objects in the database? Kind of reverse engineer the info from tnsnames.ora?

Comment: Why not just copy the file? And no, you can't do that from inside the database. What exactly are you looking for? You must already be connected to the DB so you know the listener address/port/service of *this* database - so what are you looking for, information on other databases included in the `tnsnames.ora` (which would be a security issue if this DB revealed it)? Alternative service names? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for picking the question. I'm interested in accessing data from configuration files or possibly alert.log and listener.log -- if that same data is stored within the database and I can query it, that would be awesome. I guess it could be possible to get some information by querying system views. But alert.log access from within oracle? I'm thinking it could be done with a java program that can access the file and write the output back to database for querying. Some other ideas?